# Redirecting visitors to different landing pages based on referral URLs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, cookies, referrals

I have no experience with JavaScript/CSS/HTML, so I hope someone can give me some instructions. I would like to write and integrate a javascript script on a website to group visitors based on their referral URLs (e.g. if partner website or not), then to retarget them to specific contents on the website (landing pages) based on which visitor group they belong to. I only need basic script to illustrate the idea, as part of multidisciplinary project (academic purpose). Many thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: this can ultimately be done with many methods, if/else or switch and so on. You did not display any type of code or give any detail how you plan to retrieve the referral URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PHPNoob. I was recommended to use the Document.referrer API to retrieve the URL, I am not sure how to do that and how to separate the URLs from partner website (versus other websites), before redirecting the visitors to relevant landing pages. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very basic information provided, from a high level you could do it as in a JS file.

```
let refer = document.referrer;

   if(refer == "www.example.com"){
     window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/index1";
} else if(refer == "www.example2.com"){
     window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/index2";
} else {
     window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/index3";
}
```